# Apache Tomcat cannot start due to InvalidJarIndexError: Invalid index

Tags: java, tomcat

I am migrating an Apache Tomcat application from being generated by a build.xml to a Maven project.

After installing the new jars I am getting an `InvalidJarIndexError: Invalid index` error on Tomcat start up.

I can see in catalina.log that Tomcat Native library cannot be found right before the sever error, however I can also see older logs that it cannot be found when Tomcat was able to start up.  Previously it was not for openSLL however.

I have already check for any corrupted jars on the system and cannot find any.

I also added tried adding tomcat-native-2.0.4.jar to /usr/local but still get the same error.

```
05-Mar-2019 13:56:15.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

vs

```
22-Jun-2023 18:36:02.206 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
```

This is the full stack trace of the error I am getting.  I am not sure if this is related the the Tomcat Native library or if there is some other problem given that it was previously not able to find it.

```
23-Jun-2023 09:37:19.274 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
23-Jun-2023 09:37:19.799 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Error initializing Catalina
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[8005]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
        Caused by: jdk.internal.util.jar.InvalidJarIndexError: Invalid index
                at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1051)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:962)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:937)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:296)
                at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:629)
                at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:627)
                at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
                at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:626)
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1403)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.loadDescriptors(Registry.java:678)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.findDescriptor(Registry.java:724)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.findManagedBean(Registry.java:504)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:639)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:156)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:57)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:994)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above jar index error was cause by incompatible jars in the tomcat/lib directory.

Once the offending jar was removed the InvalidJarIndexError: Invalid index was resolved.